# PHP classes for facebook, twitter and google

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

I am looking for php wrapper classes for `Facebook`, `Twitter` and `Google`. I need to use these functionalities:

- Login
- Post to wall/twitter feed

Are there any good classes available that you know of? Or am I better of writing them myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to signup on phpclasses.org which is totally free. and then you can download these classes. along with documentation.

**php wrapper class for facebook**:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5200-PHP-Facebook-API-wrapper.html

**php wrapper class for twitter**:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4075-PHP-Set-and-retrieve-Twitter-user-status.html

**php wrapper class for google**:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/920-PHP-PHP-class-library-to-access-the-Google-API-viaSOAP.html

I'm using one in my project.

please also give a go to follwoing links, (Step by step guide):

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/login-with-facebook-and-twitter.html

http://www.pakt.com/pakt/?id=5e17b48f5679ab47

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need to sign up, if just want to download the classes…

Comment: Alright, once i needed classes for email piping. It required me to signup first. then i was able to download. but anyways these classes helps alot.

Comment: They do, but the first class doesn't really support user login etc right? It seems more useful when they are already logged in.

Comment: The last links will help you in login etc.

Comment: The php wrapper for Twitter is out of date. Made in 2009 supports only Basic Authentication which is removed a long time ago!

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

For Twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php

For Google, it depends of what web service are you going to use (Calendar, Google+, etc).

Basically, their authentification process works using oAuth. You have a lot of information about it on Google. Furthermore, there are some classes for some PHP frameworks as CodeIgniter (if you use one of them).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Facebook's SDK for PHP:

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Here you can find a documentation on how to use the Facebook's API:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook you should check their [Facebook for Websites](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) manual where you have everything explained, along with some code samples.